# C# How to set List with other class as type as property

Tags: c#, list, class, properties

I have two classes. First class is "StoreList":

```
class StoreList
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
}
```

Second is DataList:

```
class DataList
{
    public List<StoreList> StoreListData { get; set; } //I don't know if this is correct
}
```

So I can use in code like this:

```
var liststoreIds = client.storeList(sessionId); //here I get data from API, all ok

var storeList = new DataList();

foreach (var stores in liststoreIds)
{
    storeList.StoreListData.Add(new StoreList
    {
         Code = stores.code,
         Name = stores.name,
         StoreId = stores.store_id
    });
}
```

In code I get error: **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."** Where is a problem?

Comment: How can you `Add()` to `StorelistData` when its never been initialized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the list, either in the constructor or inline:

```
class DataList
{
    public List<StoreList> StoreListData { get; set; } = new List<StoreList>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that you can initialize like this. Now @macceltura don't mar question as possible duplicate. I whant to mark your question as solution, what do you recomend?